# Run-Time Conditional Fields in Structs in C

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, runtime, conditional-statements

I have a specific application written in C that needs to be memory efficient. It is collecting statistics, so I need to be able to "turn on/off" certain fields in run-time to minimize the memory consumption. 
I know you can define conditional struct fields using macros but that is compile-time if I'm not mistaken, is there a possible way of doing this in C in run-time?

Example:

input :

```
collect (A,B)
```

will result in a struct like this:

```
struct statistics{
double A;
double B;
};
```

but input:

```
collect (A,B,C)
```

will result in a struct like this:

```
struct statistics{
double A;
double B;
double C;
};
```

Comment: You would need to use some sort of dynamic allocation and structure.

Comment: In that case it would be better to use a dynamically-sized array for each record rather than a struct (assuming all your fields are the same type, i.e. `double` ?). Alternatively you could switch from AoS to SoA, where each array is a pointer and is only allocated if needed.

Comment: Right, (they are not all double but mostly double and integer); however, a pointer is 4-bytes itself, so instead of each of all these fields, I will have a pointer, which may or may not be allocated--but still around the same order in memory. Is it possible to do better than that?

Comment: I've fleshed out my latter suggestion above into a fuller answer below now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to turn-off certain fields inside the struct at run-time.  You can however have a pointer that points to a dynamically allocated array of doubles that can represent multiple fields.
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stats
{
    size_t number_of_doubles;
    double* data;
};

void make_stats(struct stats* pStats)
{
    pStats->number_of_doubles = 3;
    pStats->data = (double*) malloc(pStats->number_of_doubles * sizeof(double));
}

void delete_stats(struct stats* pStats)
{
    free(pStats->data);
}

int main()
{
    struct stats foo;

    make_stats(&foo);

    foo.data[0] = 3.0;
    foo.data[1] = 5.0;
    foo.data[2] = 7.0;

    delete_stats(&foo);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess this will work, I need to change the number_of_doubles to some sort of flag for existence or nonexistence of certain statistics-- but I guess this works.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've added a main for you to try out and the delete.  Please flag as answered if this was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the usual array of structs (AoS):

```
struct statistics{
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;
};

struct statistics my_statistics = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(my_statistics[0]));

my_statistics[0].A = 1;
my_statistics[0].B = 2;
my_statistics[0].C = 3;
```

you could switch to a struct of arrays (SoA):

```
struct statistics{
    double *A;
    double *B;
    double *C;
};

struct statistics my_statistics;

my_statistics.A = using_A ? malloc(1000000 * sizeof(my_statistics.A[0])) : NULL;
my_statistics.B = using_B ? malloc(1000000 * sizeof(my_statistics.B[0])) : NULL;
my_statistics.C = using_C ? malloc(1000000 * sizeof(my_statistics.C[0])) : NULL;

my_statistics.A[0] = 1;
my_statistics.B[0] = 2;
my_statistics.C[0] = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for the demonstration sir! Considering the number of statistics collected are beyond 100, this will still have at least a 4bytes*100 size struct.

Comment: Sure - I don't know how much data you're collecting and what your memory constraints are, so it's not easy to give an optimal solution. If memory is *really* tight then go with dynamically sized arrays - that has slightly less overhead but the price is more complicated access to individual elements.

Comment: @user2662165: PS: you do realise that there is only *one* instance of the above struct in the AoS case ?

Comment: yes, in fact it would be useful if not for the following situation: I still need to maintain an array of structs because every instance has different fields based on what it needs to collect-- so, one instance would be collecting A and B, while the other one is collecting A,B and C. so it would get a bit more complicated if I implement it as a SoAs. now if I go with an AoS like above and assign a flag to each instance to show what it is collecting, I will know how big the array of data inside  the struct is and which positions belong to each field and so on...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to alter the size of a struct at runtime. The size of a struct is built into the executable's instructions whenever you allocate them on the stack or on the heap. As another example, `sizeof` of a struct is available at compile time, so it can not be altered at runtime.

Of course, you can have custom structs with a custom memory manager to do that, but it's not built right into the language.